# Python3 GZip Compressing String

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

I am trying to do the following with Python3:

```
data = json.dumps(packet)
s = StringIO()
g = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='w')
g.write(data)
g.close()
gzipped_body = s.getvalue()
```

But it keeps complaining with the following error:

```
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

The example code I'm using is based on Python2 so I am thinking there is some changes in StringIO that might be causing this but I'm not sure. Anyone give me some hints on how to get a gzipped string of some JSON in Python3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like this might have gotten a lot easier in Python3. This code seems to work so far:

```
data = bytes(json.dumps(packet), 'utf-8')
s_out = gzip.compress(data)
```

Comment: `bytes()` is an easy way to convert `StringIO()`'s `.getvalue()` string to bytes! Then you can gzip it.